# calculating svd using eigen-vectors of matrix * (matrix')

Tags: octave, svd, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I read about [Singular Value Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition). To quote wikipedia :

```
The left-singular vectors of M are eigenvectors of MM∗.
The right-singular vectors of M are eigenvectors of M∗M.
The non-zero singular values of M (found on the diagonal entries of Σ) 
are the square roots of the non-zero eigenvalues of both M∗M and MM∗
```

I wrote this octave code (console output is shown here) :

`a` is the matrix whose svd is being calculated.

```
octave:1> a = [1,3;3,1]
a =

   1   3
   3   1

octave:3> [U,S,V] = svd(a)
U =

  -0.70711  -0.70711
  -0.70711   0.70711

S =

Diagonal Matrix

   4   0
   0   2

V =

  -0.70711   0.70711
  -0.70711  -0.70711
```

Check if svd really works ..

```
octave:4> U*S*V
ans =

   3.00000  -1.00000
   1.00000  -3.00000

octave:5> U*S*V'
ans =

   1.00000   3.00000
   3.00000   1.00000
```

Now try first principle (wikipedia) style :

```
octave:6> b = a*a'
b =

   10    6
    6   10

octave:7> c = a'*a
c =

   10    6
    6   10

octave:8> [E1,L1] = eig(b)
E1 =

  -0.70711   0.70711
   0.70711   0.70711

L1 =

Diagonal Matrix

    4    0
    0   16

octave:9> [E2,L2] = eig(c)
E2 =

  -0.70711   0.70711
   0.70711   0.70711

L2 =

Diagonal Matrix

    4    0
    0   16
```

I can see that eigen-values of `b` and `c` are squares of singular-values of `a`. This is cool. But `left-singular-vectors` and `right-singular-vectors` are coming wrong... sign problem.

What extra step is required to get the right values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you already have the right values.

Eigenvectors are defined up to a multiplicative constant. This is obvious from [their definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors). So in your case `[-0.70711; -0.70711]` and `[0.70711; 0.70711]` are equivalent.

And in both cases the `[-1; 1]` eigenvector corresponds to the sqrt(4) = 2 eigenvalue, while the `[1; 1]` eigenvector corresponds to the sqrt(16) = 4 eigenvalue.